# To Load user control using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

In the below Code i have a user control i want to bind user control using ajax web method.I tried no idea to solve it .Pls help me to solve the issue.

Sample.aspx

```
<test:school ID="usr" runat="server"/>


[WebMethod]
public static string LoadUserControl()
{
 TestSchool.SchoolBusinessLyr.SchoolBizClient SelectDistrict = new TestSchool.SchoolBusinessLyr.SchoolBizClient();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = SelectDistrict.SelectDistrict();
usr.field=ds.Tables[0];
usr.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind an existing user control using AJAX; you can return data to the client, which JavaScript can then update the UI where the user control is (programmatically), or you can use an UpdatePanel to update the UI from the server... you can also return the HTML of the user control, but that is a little more complicated...

Comment: Can u please  illustrate by example to return data to the client, which JavaScript can then update the UI where the user control is (programmatically)

Comment: Remember a user control only renders out HTML - really, what I'm saying has nothing to do with the user control, but the HTML rendered.  Anything updated via AJAX (like markup) will not be sent back and retained to the server unless it's an input field (text, hidden, etc.)  There are tons of examples of updating HTML online from an AJAX call...